# Getting number of followers of a Twitter user using Twitter API for free

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I wrote a Twitter bot written in Python 3-4 years back, using tweepy which used to tweet about new followers gained in a day for a specific user ID. I tried reviving it today, but it started giving these errors.

> tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden 453 - You currently have access
> to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints
> (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint,
> you may need a different access level. You can learn more here:
> https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product

The code is straightforward :

```
import tweepy
import sys

def main():
    ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXX'
    ACCESS_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
    CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    Past_Followers = int(read_prev_followers_from_file())
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    usr= api.get_user(screen_name='@id')
    Current_Followers = usr.followers_count
    print("Current followers : " + str(Current_Followers))
    diff=Current_Followers-Past_Followers
    stat='Total Followers = '+str(Current_Followers)+'. New Followers Today = '+str(diff)
    api.update_status(status=stat)
    write_curr_followers_to_file(Current_Followers)
```

The response seems to specify that now I cannot get the number of followers of a particular twitter user using the twitter API **for free**. I tried using the twitter V2 API free version as well but there only the following endpoint is exposed through which I can get only my user ID's information.

> GET /2/users/me
>
> Client.get_me()

So is it the end of the road for this task or there exists a way to resolve this?

Comment: You'd need the _Enterprise_ access to access followers.